# ASP.NET web forms equivalent of Razor's @{ }

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms

I can't phrase this accurately enough to find the appropriate result on google. In Razor you can nest blocks of .NET code (the key being multi-line use) within a view with these tags:

```
@{
   ...
}
```

What is the web forms equivalent?

Comment: Down-vote-and-runs eh?

Answer (score 4):

You can us [Embedded code blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx).

```
<% %> runs server-side code, like an if-else block, for loop, etc.
```

For example:

```
<% if(condition)
   {
       // Do something here

   }
   else
   {
       // Do something else here
   }
%>
```

There are several other varieties of these:

```
<%# %> is for data-binding expressions
<%= %> is the equivalent of `Response.Write()`
<%: %> is for HTML-encoding the data
<%@ %> is for directives, usually page directives in ASP.NET
```

Comment: And `<%$ %>` for accessing resources

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX):

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <% for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) %>
       <% { Response.Write("<br>" + i.ToString()); }%>
    </form>
</body>
```

And another example:

```
<script runat=server>
protected String GetTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("t");
}
</script>
<html>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       Current server time is <% =GetTime()%>.
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  can nest blocks of code within: `<% ... %>`